# How can I detach two dependent applications?

Tags: architecture, osgi, system, n-tier-architecture

I have a backend platform that serves two different frontend applications. One is a very complicated application (Application A) with a small user base and lots of interdependent processes, and the other application (Application B) has a larger user base but is simpler and has less interdependent processes.

The backend platform is based on a micro services architecture, for example session handling (login access) is handled by a separate process, all outbound channels are separate processes and inbound channels are separate processes. Each of the applications is also a process. The design is 3 tier, with osgi plugins.

Management is thinking about separating Application A from B, so that release planning and deployment is more flexible and the costs are more transparent.

The applications on the server share some basic stuff, like session handling (for example being able to login) and the architecture for the micro services (fault tolerance, etc). The client applications also share some code, like graph logic, etc. Application A and B share the same database.

What would be some best practice ways to detach these two applications? Ideally application A should not affected.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I could envisage is a Fork and Merge strategy.

The platform plugins that Application B requires are defined and baselined and become the minimal platform. The business logic plugins that compromise Application B are deployed with the minimal platform. Any important changes to the platform are merged back into the minimal platform. The databases would also be split. Does anyone see any flaws with this strategy, or have a better idea?